# How to add a push pin to a MKMapView(IOS) when touching?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, pushpin

I had to get the coordinate of a point where the user touch on a MKMapView.
I'm not working with the Interface Builder.
Can you give me one example?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

You can use a [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilongpressgesturerecognizer) for this.  Wherever you create or initialize the mapview, first attach the recognizer to it:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0; //user needs to press for 2 seconds
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
[lpgr release];
```

Then in the gesture handler:

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
        return;

    CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.mapView];   
    CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate = 
        [self.mapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];

    YourMKAnnotationClass *annot = [[YourMKAnnotationClass alloc] init];
    annot.coordinate = touchMapCoordinate;
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annot];
    [annot release];
}
```

YourMKAnnotationClass is a class you define that conforms to the [MKAnnotation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotation) protocol.  If your app will only be running on iOS 4.0 or later, you can use the pre-defined [MKPointAnnotation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkpointannotation) class instead.

For examples on creating your own MKAnnotation class, see the sample app [MapCallouts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mapkit_annotations/annotating_a_map_with_custom_data).

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks.  Personally I flipped the if-statement to a `==` so it returns if it *isn't* `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`. Doing this will drop the pin after the specified time, even if the user is still holding the map which was desirable for me (and how the official Maps app does it).

Comment: I would just like to say I implemented your answer into my project and it worked like a charm. Thank you for your most excellent answer.

Comment: This woks perfect but only in the simmulator for me. No callback on the physical phone. Any ideas? I'm running iOS5 with ARC.

Comment: @rjgonzo: Should work fine with iOS5, ARC, and device.  Try deleting app from device and doing Clean, Rebuild, and re-install.  While running on device, add breakpoints or NSLogs to make sure mapView is not nil when adding lpgr.

Comment: Is it possible to do this animated?

Comment: `release`... The memories!

Answer (score 34):

Thanks to Anna for providing such a great answer! Here is a Swift version if anybody is interested (the answer has been updated to Swift 4.1 syntax).

Creating UILongPressGestureRecognizer:

```
let longPressRecogniser = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MapViewController.handleLongPress(_:)))
longPressRecogniser.minimumPressDuration = 1.0
mapView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecogniser)
```

Handling the gesture:

```
@objc func handleLongPress(_ gestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer){
    if gestureRecognizer.state != .began { return }

    let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: mapView)
    let touchMapCoordinate = mapView.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)

    let album = Album(coordinate: touchMapCoordinate, context: sharedContext)

    mapView.addAnnotation(album)
}
```

Comment: Wow... I didn't notice this and spent a long time converting it.

Comment: It is possible to use _**let longPressRecogniser = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleLongPress:")**_

Comment: @Dx_ yes you can because the recognizer is not being modified. The properties in the recognizer are being modified.

Comment: I get error messages in Swift 3. The error is: "Use of unresolved identifier 'gestureRecogniser'

Anyone got a solution?

Comment: Hi @PhilipS, I've updated my answer to Swift 3.0 syntax. I hope it will help.

Comment: I get error message in swift 4.2 this error is : "Use of unresolved identifier 'Album'"