# how to find longitude and latitude for mapview in xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.5

In my application I need to first pin annotation when ever I click the map and know to longitude and latitude of this point and after this both longitude and latitude I want to print on only one label, tell me how can I do  this?

I tried following code, But no help.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
  { 
    static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[PlaceMark class]]) {

    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [myMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    return annotationView;
  }

  return nil; 
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806628/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-lat-long-of-mkmapview-of-touch-position-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 1):

From this you can get the lat and long of annotation

for getting the latitude use this

```
[[[view annotation] coordinate].latitude
```

And longitude like this

```
 [[[view annotation] coordinate]. longitude
```