# MkMapView drop a pin on touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, ios-simulator

I am struggling to unearth a standard way to drop a pin on a MkMapView based on a touch input. There probably isnt a standard way, but it is always worth asking. If I have to implement this myself is the best approach to add a Gesture Recogniser to pick up a tap on the map view.

Comment: This tutorial has lot more stuffs, it gives u what exactly want https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to do this.

This previous answer of mine has details with sample code:
[How to add a push pin to a MKMapView(IOS) when touching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959994/how-to-add-a-push-pin-to-a-mkmapviewios-when-touching/3960754#3960754)

To animate the drop, in `viewForAnnotation`, return an `MKPinAnnotationView` with `animatesDrop` set to YES.

Comment: Yeah I saw your post before, I though this would be the only way to do it.

Answer (score -3):

I know that the Maps app has a separate button (under the curl of the map) that drops a pin.  Hence that is kind of how I do it (though not under the map curl).  I have not read anywhere that there is a standard but I have not read all 12,000 GB of documentation (ha ha).  I would say to check out some of the "standard" apps like Maps and follow what they do just to be consistent.  I know that typically a double tap zooms the map so I'm not sure that I would use that.  Just my $0.02...

Comment: In maps if you long press it drops a pin.

Comment: Well I never knew that, thanks for the info!  Then maybe that would be how I do it and maybe I'll re-work mine to do the same.