# Selecting Location from MapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mapkit, cllocation

I was thinking of an application where user could select a location on an iphone app. I have googled it and didn't find anything useful.

My question is, is it possible to let the user select a location from an iphone app using MapKit/CLLocation? If yes, please help me where should i start.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a long press gesture recognizer to the map:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer* lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.5;
lpgr.delegate = self;
[self.map addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
[lpgr release];
```

In the handle long press method get the CLLocationCordinate2D:

```
- (void) handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    /*
     Only handle state as the touches began
     set the location of the annotation
     */

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [self.map convertPoint:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.map] toCoordinateFromView:self.map];

    [self.map setCenterCoordinate:coordinate animated:YES];

  // Do anything else with the coordinate as you see fit in your application

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959994/how-to-add-a-push-pin-to-a-mkmapviewios-when-touching). The answer tells you not only how to get the coordinate, but also how to put a pin (annotation) on the map.