# How to do a long press in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to implement a long press on a mapView in Swift (to achieve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959994/how-to-add-a-push-pin-to-a-mkmapviewios-when-touching/3960754#3960754))

I don't get any compiler errors but when I do the longpress in the simulator the app crashes with "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

I suspect it's something to do with selectors (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift)) but every combination I've tried fails

I have this in viewDidLoad:

```
var lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "action") 

lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0; 

mapView.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)
```

and this in the ViewController class:

```
func action(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) { 

println("long press") 

}
```

Comment: "action" should be "action:"

Comment: That does it - thanks! Will mark as the answer

Comment: @0x7fffffff He wants to accept your answer. post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 16):

The method signature of the method:

```
func action(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) { }
```

Needs to include a colon for its parameter. You should be using this.

```
var lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "action:")
```