# Swift 3 MKMapView - Add pin/annotation on long press

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to set up my `MKMapView` so that when I press and hold the map for 2 seconds, a pin will appear at the user's current location.

Here is what I have in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
let gestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:(Selector(("longPress:"))))
gestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 2.0
gestureRecognizer.delegate = self
map.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

Then at the bottom of my ViewController class I have the following:

```
func longPress(gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    let coordinate = map.centerCoordinate

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = coordinate
    map.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

When I run the app and press on the map for 2 seconds, the app crashes. The console says

> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

and

> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f89f0c02ad0

and I am not sure why. Thank you for any guidance you can offer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681275/how-to-do-a-long-press-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never say

```
Selector(("longPress:"))
```

Say

```
#selector(longPress)
```

Comment: Simple solution, completely fixed my problem. Thank you!

Comment: I like when that happens. :) Seriously use `#selector` syntax; its purpose is to prevent _exactly_ the error you got.