# How to add annotation manually to map view in iOS?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkitannotation

I'd like to add annotation manually (when user touch in to the particular place in map view) and to get the details of that location (latitude,longitude,address)..

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959994/how-to-add-a-push-pin-to-a-mkmapviewios-when-touching/3960754#3960754

Comment: @iPrabu - how to get the location details and how to change the annotation position ..

Answer (score 0):

as @iPrabu directed to [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959994/how-to-add-a-push-pin-to-a-mkmapviewios-when-touching/3960754#3960754), with very good and correct answer for your problem... for second part i.e. to get details about that location..you can do something like this

```
-(void)getAddressFromCurruntLocation:(CLLocation *)location{

CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
 {
     if(placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)
     {
         CLPlacemark *placemark= [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];



         NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[placemark country],[placemark administrativeArea]];
// you may also get locality,sublocality,subadministrativeare etc
         NSLog(@"The Address Is:%@",address);
     }
 }];
}
```

Happy Coding :)